# Why don't any of my electric ovens actually keep the temperature that is displayed?

Tags: oven, temperature

I had an older oven that was consistently 25-50 degrees Fahrenheit lower than what it was set to be and what the display unit stated. I purchased an oven thermometer and keep it inside to check the temperature. The oven display would show 450, but the thermometer inside would be 425 or even 400.

Thinking it was a problem with the oven, my landlord replaced it with a brand new oven. The first day I had the new oven, the temperature was maybe 10 degrees lower than it displayed. Yay, problem fixed, right? Sadly, no. Now, over time, the new oven gets *really* inconsistent temperatures. Sometimes it is 25-50 degrees cooler, and sometimes it is 25-50 degrees (or more) hotter! As you can imagine, this is causing a lot of issues with cooking.

Since the problem is likely not the ovens themselves, as two different ovens are displaying this behavior, does anyone have any suggestions about what could be going wrong?

Comment: Pre-heating for an extra 5 or 10 mins should help keep the temp more consistent. So will adding thermal mass, like a baking stone or some cast iron pieces. Lastly, adding convection (ex wind-up fan) should shorten the cycles, reducing the intensity of over and under shoot.

Answer (score 3):

A variance of 50 degrees or more - both high & low - sounds extreme.

However, a consistent *offset* of 25 to 50 degrees is actually not that unusual. Hypothetically, that could be 35 degrees miscalibration of the thermostat combined with a 15 degree temperature swing between cycles. I don't know what the typical temperature swing is for a residential oven. For a typical HVAC thermostat, a typical temperature swing is +2, -1, or 3 degrees total - so 5 degrees if you include the extra degree in each direction to actually trigger any action. I am sure an oven will have a wider range - the chicken or cake is not as sensitive to minor variations as people are.

Thermostats are manufactured to behave a particular way, but I highly doubt they are factory calibrated, just as mass-produced cars aren't taken out on the highway before being delivered in order to make sure the speedometer accurately reads 65 MPH.

Many ovens now have a user-accessible calibration feature. For example, [Kitchenaid has a page describing the calibration process](https://producthelp.kitchenaid.com/Cooking/Wall_Ovens_and_Ranges/Product_Info/Oven_Product_Assistance/How_to_Calibrate_the_Oven).

You can also determine your oven temperature with sugar! You don't actually need a thermometer. (And thermometers themselves are often miscalibrated.) A quick search finds [How to Test Your Oven Temperature with Sugar](https://www.allrecipes.com/article/how-to-test-your-oven-temperature-with-sugar/), though I first read about it in [The Science of Cooking](https://amzn.to/3hztmC5):
[image]

which is well worth reading for anyone interested in both science *and* cooking.

Answer (score 2):

Electric ovens are known for inaccurate temp readings. A lot has to do with the area that you place your small oven thermometer. If you place it closer to the elements, you'll get a higher reading and it will fluctuate as the oven cycles. The other problem is the temperature probe for your oven. It's usually right up close to the top element and on the side so it's prone to read higher. Make sure it's always clean. Some experimenting with the location of this probe can reduce the errors in the readings.
All you can really is use your separate oven thermometer and get a feel for how the oven will operate. Check it often.

Answer (score 2):

The technology to have the reading be accurate exists, but (most? all?) appliance makers don't bother. Likewise, they don't bother making the actual set temp be tightly accurate, though that technology also exists, albeit at a higher cost (which appliance makers hate) than an accurate built-in thermometer.

A previous oven would display what appeared to be accurate and detailed temperatures during pre-heat, but had two noticeable flaws - if you did something like opening the door, the display did not go down, it only went up, so if the temp dropped, it lied and said it was as high as it had ever gotten. Once "at the set temp" it would lie and display the set temp regardless of actual temperature. Presumably this "display logic" was to prevent complaints about the oven not being exactly the temperature set, at least as shown by the oven itself. That one could be faked out by altering to a higher temperature than set, where it would reveal the actual temperature it was starting from until it got to the new setting and lied again.

I have yet to meet any digital temp set/display oven (the norm now) that offers any greater accuracy than the old mechanical dial did (and many are worse, even if you did get to know that grandma's oven was 25 degrees low and uncle's was 50 degrees high, at least they were usually consistently that way.) There was and is some hysteresis or deadband in the thermostats - 25 degrees is not unusual. 50 either way is a but much. 5 degrees or less is easily achieved, but it's not actually done, due to penny pinching and lack of competition (not seen as a sales point, presumably) among appliance makers.